# React setState causes a crash

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am doing an axios call on a backend script that returns a JSON array including details. The back end script goes below:

```
app.get('/getAllData', cors(), function (req, res) {


    findAll().then((result) => {
        // res.writeHead(200)
        res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
        res.send(result)
        res.end()
    })


});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

`findAll()` is the async function that reads data from the database and returns the array. I have hit the URL multiple times and got the result.

Now when I try to do an axios call from react frontend, the results show up good in the console of the browser. But when I try to store the result in the state of the class, it causes the application to crash. Here is the react function below:

```
  makeSongCards = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getAllData")
      .then((result) => {
        const data = result.data
        console.log(result.data);
        // this.setState({res:data})
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err));;
```

Also P.S. the `console.log(result.data);` statement prints twice in the console of the browser for some reason. I don't if it's relevant but I find it weird.

**Update:**

Initial state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { res: [] }
  }
```

Comment: Could you give error message after setState?

Comment: also share your initial state

Comment: @kadash there are no error messages after setState. It says all okay but when I load the page using the browser, the console.log line keeps on printing.

Comment: @MonzoorTamal I have added the initial state

Comment: how did you call makeSongCards Fn
`there are no error messages after setState. It says all okay but when I load the page using the browser, the console.log line keeps on printing.`
this mean you page is re rendering every time.

Comment: @MonzoorTamal I am calling it before the return of the render function.

Comment: @AniruddhaBera that's the problem. If you use hook then use call the the fn under useEffect. if you class based then use componentDidMount and call the fn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218188/discussion-between-aniruddha-bera-and-monzoor-tamal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeSongCards` should not be called directly in the `render` method, but inside a lifecycle method, such as `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`. The reason for this is, that you update the state, and if you update the state during render it will restart the render cycle and you will end up in an infinite loop as you do now.

Try making the call in `componentDidMount` instead of `render` and let me know if the infinite `console.log` goes away.

Also, it is not clear what do you mean by crash? Does the backend server crash or does the frontend application? What do you mean by crash exactly?

Comment: This solved my problem. But I am facing a new problem as of now. :(